# webkit raster vs vector images

Tags: android, html, vector, webkit, resolution

I am trying to address a resolution issue when designing HTML for webkit browsers.
So basically the problem is that webkit browsers can have resolution anywhere from 240x320 to 960x640 and I can't have a separate image/icon set for each one but I do want the pages to look the same on all devices (or very close at least).

Scaling the image (working with percentages) works but it's a performance degrade:
http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html#SpecifyImageDimensions

The other option is using vector graphics which is supported in webkit but I am not aware of the performance implications that is going to have on the pages/app.

The other option is to have a few icon sets for some standard well know resolutions and when you get a browser which is outside of these groups you apply some minor scaling on the set which is closest to the users native resolution.

So basically what I am asking is, what would be the best route to achieve this with performance in mind?

Thanks
-Assaf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Vector graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) are *always* more expensive in terms of runtime performance as complex equations are run to create them. Having said that, I'm not sure if they're redrawn every frame from scratch, or if the result's cached unless it's in a dirty state.

I'd suggest having a few different icon sets for well known resolutions and applying minor scaling if required.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is not helpful at all. Vector graphics can be just as small as a PNG, and used right can support transparency and various other good features.

The only problem is if your looking for pixel perfect perfection having some of the images scale up might cause problems.

You can also use illustrator to html5 canvas plugin to export directly to html5 canvas.

For our webkit browsers on row icons, we set a property that doesn't allow webkit to scale the icons for desktop browsers. Or for some of the icons we include a small SVG.

They are well supported and work great. Even better would be to use a free font creation tool and paste your vector graphics from illustrator into a font, so that you could use web-font to simply call up ANY size icon, as simple text. We use this technic.